# Adding a check for days in a leap year inside a while loop

Tags: java

Hey guys I've got this while loop which is checking for a valid input from user for a date. I need to add a check to this while loop, if its not a leap year day cannot be more than 28 and if it is a leap year day cannot be more than 29 ONLY if month is february, meaning month = 2 .

How would I go about it? I know that to check if its a leap year I use this statement: `if ((year%4 == 0 && year%100 !=0) || (year%400 == 0))` .

Here is my loop :

```
while ((day>31 || day<=0) || (month>12 || month<=0) || (year<=0))          
    {                                                                             
    System.out.println("The original date/month/year is invaild");
    System.out.println("Please enter 3 integers to represent a valid date:");
    day = scan.nextInt();
    month = scan.nextInt();
    year = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

BTW, I cant use any methods or classes, it's an homework assignment .

Comment: When you say you "can't use any methods or classes" - presumably you could write your *own* method, couldn't you? That's what I'd do - don't try to put everything in one giant condition, but write an `isValidDate(int year, int month, int day)` method.

Comment: Use Calendar to get actual maximum for days of month. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: @mrmcwolf I think the one clear part here is: he is supposed to write his own date validation. It is homework. You are basically telling him to cheat out of the *core* part of that.

Comment: Nope , i cant . We didnt reach to that level yet . That's part of our restrictions ;/

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you are asking for, but you don't need to push everything into the while condition directly. You can do something like:

```
 boolean isDateValid = false;
 while (! isDateValid) {
    System.out.println("The original date/month/year is invaild");
    System.out.println("Please enter 3 integers to represent a valid date:");
    day = scan.nextInt();
    month = scan.nextInt();
    year = scan.nextInt();
    isDateValid = ... that lengthy conditition
 }
```

Of course, this isnt exactly nice, as the user is first greeted with an error message that doesnt make sense. So, we can turn around things and use a do/while loop instead:

```
 boolean isDateValid = false;
 do {
    System.out.println("Please enter 3 integers to represent a valid date:");
    day = scan.nextInt();
    month = scan.nextInt();
    year = scan.nextInt();
    isDateValid = ... that lengthy conditition
    if (!isDateValid) {
      System.out.println("The original date/month/year is invalid; please try again");
    }
 } while (!isDateValid)
```

And for the actual checking, simply start with separating things in your mind - what aspects need to be checked, like:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
```

a method that returns true if year is actually a leap year.

You can build plenty of such small helper methods that check **different** aspects of your problem. And in the end, you bring those little pieces together to do all the required checking.

Comment: At that part I'd probably make it a `do`/`while` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: @shaike Feel free to give some feedback if you found my input helpful ... or if there are specific things that you need more info on.

Comment: I really appreciate your help , and i understood what you have suggested . Thing is i cant create my own methods , i need to do it all in loops or switch / if statements .